# Delphi (XE2): Trial - what can I do? What about my old Delphi?

Tags: delphi, licensing, trial

I have been at RAD Studio XE2 World Tour here in Poland in Cracov and I really love new features, so Im almost sure, Ill buy it. But now I downloaded trial version and I want to ask about two things:

Firstly: What can I do with it? I mean - can I build for example one free application and distribute it over Internet? It would be freeware application written within these 30 days. License is quite long and I cant find restrictions like that.

Secondly: If I install this trial anything bad can happen to my Delphi 2009 (Professional)? I have a lot of IDE experts, additional components, important projects etc etc - I dont want to lose anything. In short - is it better to install it on VM?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed 'full' XE2 onto a VM which already had Delphi 7 and Delphi 2010 on, and haven't seen any adverse effects over the last couple of days. All 3 environments appear to get along fine, as has long been the Delphi tradition.

Once I get a chance I'll stick it on my 'main' development VM, which is currently Delphi 2007.

However, I don't know about the trial version aspect of it. I wouldn't expect it to behave any differently but if you're concerned about your production/work environment, I would strongly suggest that you isolate your trial explorations to a VM... - just to be safe. :-)

Comment: I cant accept both answers ;/ Yours and Bobs ^^... But thank you very much for answer!

Comment: The inability to accept multiple answers is one reason you shouldn't put multiple distinct questions in a single post. You should have posted one question about what you're allowed to do with trial-created programs, and then posted another question about how well the trial works with other versions installed on the same computer.

Comment: @RobKennedy - all right - Ill remember :) But still I think it should be possible to accept multiple answers, because sometimes question can be more complex and more answers can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to distribute applications or components written with the trial edition of Delphi.

Comment: All right, thanks for your answer. What about second question?

Comment: Negative. Embarkadero has no power to take over OP's rights for his own work. ∴ he can distribute his work in the source code form w/o any doubts.

Comment: Bob, I know you are an official reseller, but I'd really appreciate some reference / citation here. The license supplied with XE2 Trial is not limiting in any such way.